# Range of dispel magic greater when used as area dispel

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Dispel magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) is a medium range spell. [Dispel Magic Greater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) says it functions like dispel magic, so it inherits the range.

However, dispel magic greater has another option called area dispel.

> Area Dispel: When greater dispel magic is used in this way, the spell affects everything within a 20-foot-radius burst. Roll one dispel check and apply that check to each creature in the area, as if targeted by dispel magic. For each object within the area that is the target of one or more spells, apply the dispel check as with creatures. Magic items are not affected by an area dispel.

It now says that its a 20-foot-radius burst, but does not mentioned that it is centered on you. So does this mean you have the ability to cast the spell away from your as the burst effect?

Under the [aiming magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) is a subsection called Burst, Emanation, or Spread.

> Most spells that affect an area function as a burst, an emanation, or a spread. In each case, you select the spell's point of origin and measure its effect from that point.

It says nothing about bursts being centered on you and this suggests to me that I can still cast the spell at range to keep myself out of the effect.

So to make my question clear, when I use the area dispel feature of dispel magic greater, is the burst always centered on me or an I am to choose a point within medium range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range is the same as for *dispel magic*. The different target-or-area-of-effect line doesn't change the range line of the spell.

> This spell functions like dispel magic, except…

Comment: I just needed to make sure that the burst effect could still be used when it was cast away from me. I feared that burst effects only happened off the caster.